# Access to the display when loading the systemd service

Tags: systemd, xorg, services, display

I am writing a bootable service in C and D languages.

There is a database of users with thin client settings. I access this database over the network during the download and get from there the data of a specific user linked to the MAC address. The fact is that a user can have two or more monitors connected to a thin client. Data for each monitor is also loaded from the database. Using the `xrandr` source code, I wrote a program that, knowing the monitor ID, sets the desired monitor in one position or another. The fact is that `xrandr` uses the global variable `DISPLAY`, which is unavailable during the loading process.

```
● myservice-init.service - myservice
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/myservice-init.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-05-12 19:15:14 MSK; 55s ago
    Process: 1559 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/myservice-init (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 1559 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

мая 12 19:15:14 ts_d85ed3156a39 systemd[1]: Starting myservice...
мая 12 19:15:14 ts_d85ed3156a39 thinstation[1562]: Can't open display :0
мая 12 19:15:14 ts_d85ed3156a39 systemd[1]: myservice-init.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
мая 12 19:15:14 ts_d85ed3156a39 systemd[1]: myservice-init.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
мая 12 19:15:14 ts_d85ed3156a39 systemd[1]: Failed to start myservice.
```

Although, looking at the `Xorg` service - this data is there:

```
~# cat /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/50-systemd-user.sh

#!/bin/sh

systemctl --user import-environment DISPLAY XAUTHORITY

if command -v dbus-update-activation-environment >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    dbus-update-activation-environment DISPLAY XAUTHORITY
fi
```

And I start my service after downloading `xorg.service`. But even adding this code to the launch of my service, I still get errors:

```
● myservice-init.service - myservice
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/myservice-init.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-05-12 19:08:52 MSK; 18s ago
    Process: 1560 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/myservice-init (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 1560 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 12 19:08:52 ts_d85ed3156a39 systemd[1]: Starting myservice...
May 12 19:08:52 ts_d85ed3156a39 thinstation[1564]: dbus-update-activation-environment: error: unable to connect to D-Bus: Unable to autolaun
May 12 19:08:52 ts_d85ed3156a39 thinstation[1570]: Can't open display :0
May 12 19:08:52 ts_d85ed3156a39 systemd[1]: myservice-init.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 12 19:08:52 ts_d85ed3156a39 systemd[1]: myservice-init.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 12 19:08:52 ts_d85ed3156a39 systemd[1]: Failed to start myservice.
```

And if I just launch my application, then it works out quite correctly:

```
IFace("enp3s0", "e8:5b:d2:11:6a:39", "192.168.0.15")
[Monitor("VGA-1", true, 1280, 1024)]
```

UPD.

Created a user service that starts when the user is logged in, but DISPLAY is also unavailable:

```
● myservice-init.service - myservice
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/user/myservice-init.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-05-12 22:31:30 MSK; 8min ago
    Process: 2550 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/myservice-init (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 2550 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

мая 12 22:31:30 ts_d85ed3156a39 systemd[2546]: Started myservice-init.
мая 12 22:31:30 ts_d85ed3156a39 myservice-init[2551]: Can't open display :0.0
мая 12 22:31:30 ts_d85ed3156a39 systemd[2546]: myservice-init.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
мая 12 22:31:30 ts_d85ed3156a39 systemd[2546]: myservice-init.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: DISPLAY is not a "global variable" (whatever that means, which isn't much).  It's an environment variable created by X when it starts up and inherited by all child processes, to enable them to connect to that particular instance of X.  If X isn't running, then $DISPLAY either doesn't exist or isn't useful if it does (because it's not referring to a running X).   Your myservice-init.service is not running as a child of an X process, it is running as a child of systemd.  You need to understand the context your service is running in.

Comment: I don't have an answer or solution for you, but I think that any solution is likely to require extracting the details you need from your database and saving them in a file for later use by some process running under X, or using that data to change the command-line options and/or config file used to start X.  Alternatively, that process could query the database directly when it needs the data.

Comment: @cas If I'm not mistaken, then the service can be run as a custom one. But the DISPLAY variable is also unavailable there, strangely...